# Manually getting rds prices for various configs using the SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to write a function that gets the hourly pricing (using [GetProducts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_pricing_GetProducts.html)) for a the current AWS RDS on-demand configuration. Here's the problem: RDS has various versions of engines for Oracle and SQL Server:

```
oracle-ee

oracle-ee-cdb

oracle-se2

oracle-se2-cdb

sqlserver-ee

sqlserver-se

sqlserver-ex

sqlserver-web
```

I'm using the [describeDBInstances API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBInstances.html) to get details about the running RDS intance(s) on my account. However, the API doesn't return any info that helps me identify the subtypes of Oracle engines used (eg. It returns `engine = Oracle` but not whether it's `se2` or `ee`) This is mentioned in a field called `description`, however that's a varying length string so I can't consistently extract information from there

example of `description`:

```
"description": "USD 8.416 per db.r5.4xlarge.tpc2.mem4x Single-AZ instance hour (or partial hour) running Oracle EE (BYOL)"
```

The pricing details do have a field named `sku` but I can't find that anywhere in the response of `DescribeDBInstances`.

Is there any way to solve this? NOTE: I'm not using `get-cost-and-usage` because it costs quite a bit.